# Rspec response changes inbetween calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using the below line of code to check that a controller renders a response with parameters

```
expect(controller).to receive(:render).with('orders/order_pickup/layout', {:locals=>{:state=>'pickup'}})
```

But when I run the rspec test, I get...

```
 Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -["orders/order_pickup/layout", {:locals=>{:state=>"pickup"}}]
   +[]
```

However if I only delete one character from the rspec code:

```
expect(controller).to receive(:render).with('orders/order_pickup/layout', {:locals=>{:state=>'picku'}})
```

(Notice I just changed the 'locals' --> 'state' parameter to 'picku' without a 'p').  This gives a new error

```
Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -["orders/order_pickup/layout", {:locals=>{:state=>"picku"}}]
       +["orders/order_pickup/layout", {:locals=>{:state=>"pickup"}}]
```

This is exactly what I expected to get the first time!!  When I fix the typo (just add the p back), I get the first error again...

I'm confused why the 'actual' response from rpsec returns no args the first time, but returns the predicted response the second time?

## Rspec code

```
 RSpec.describe OrdersController, type: :controller do

    before do
        Order.any_instance.stub(:valid?).and_return(true)
    end

    it "should get order pickup layout if order is present" do
        order = Order.create()
        expect(controller).to receive(:render).with('orders/order_pickup/layout', {:locals=>{:state=>'pickup'}})
        get :order_pickup, :disguised_id => order.disguised_id
    end
end
```

## Controller code

```
def order_return
    @order = Order.where(disguised_id:params["disguised_id"]).first
    if @order.present?
        render "orders/order_pickup/layout", :locals => {:state => 'pickup'} 
    else 
        redirect_to "/"
    end
end
```

Comment: are you expecting there be an error the first time? it looks like there should be no error

Comment: I expect the response ["orders/order_pickup/layout", {:locals=>{:state=>"pickup"}}].  This is the expected response the 1st time and the actual response the second time.  There's an error because the first time the actual response is `no args`

Comment: Is this issue reproducible?

Comment: Yes it's reproducible